# JQuery deferred.done executes predefined function instantly, but not function declared inside

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

My problem is a weird one, as described in the title. Here's the code:

Case 1:

```
    var first = $.ajax({ // about 500ms request
        url: myUrl
        success: function() { console.log(1); }
    });

    var second = $.ajax({ // about 200 ms request
        url: myUrl
        success: function() { console.log(2); }
    });


    $.when(first, second).done(function() { console.log(3); });
```

Logs 2, 1, 3. All good, just what I wanted.

Case 2:

```
    var first = $.ajax({ // about 500ms request
        url: myUrl
        success: function() { console.log(1); }
    });

    var second = $.ajax({ // about 200 ms request
        url: myUrl
        success: function() { console.log(2); }
    });

    function logthree() {
        console.log(3);
    }


    $.when(first, second).done(logthree());
```

Logs 3, 2, 1, which is a problem. The logthree() function should only execute once first and second resolve.

Why does this happen? How can I use Case 2 without any problems?

Note: same thing happens if first and second are functions and they return an $.ajax.

Note: same thing happens if first and second are both $.get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
$.when(first, second).done(logthree);
```

You are executing `logthree()` and passing the return result to `.done()`.  You need to pass a function reference to `.done()` which is just `logthree` without the parens.  When you add parens, that instructs the JS interpreter to execute it immediately.  This is a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`$.when(first, second).done(logthree);

Comment: Thank you, it works! (Going to accept jfriend00's answer for the explanation.)